# Meta Query posts not showing on ending date of custom field

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, meta-query, date

I feel like my logic is off, but the short version is I have 2 custom fields spitting out unformated times for event-start-date and event-end-date. I don't want to show a post if the start-date is not equal or greater than today.

However, I want to show the post on the ending date. My issue is posts show up before and after the start day (this isn't mandatory but would be nice to figure out) but posts don't show up if the end date is the same as today. Is my logic in the code way off?

```
'meta_query'            => array(

    array(
        'relation'      => 'BETWEEN',
        array(
            'key'           => 'event-start-date',
            'value'     => time(),
            'compare'   => '<='
        ),
        array(
            'key'           => 'event-end-date',
            'value'     => time(),
            'compare'   => '>='
        )
    )
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What format do you save your dates as?

Comment: `BETWEEN` is not a valid value for `relation`, it's either `AND` or `OR`.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Unix Timestamps

Comment: @Milo Put in the AND. Same result as BETWEEN anyway.

Comment: Have you verified the value of `time`? Your local time and your server time are likely not the same.

Comment: @Milo Would it be just by coincidence then in this given scenario, it works perfectly unless the ending date happens to be the same date as when the page is viewed? I have verified `time`, and it's the same format, both Unix Timestamps.

Comment: I mean for example, I'm in Australia working on a client server in Los Angeles, and `time` tells me it's currently yesterday. If you `var_dump` the query object and look at `request`, you'll see the SQL query generated from your parameters and it will tell you exactly what it's looking for.